# cs2cs works one way but not the other

Tags: coordinate-system, cs2cs

I am trying to build a short program using cs2cs that will work on any windows pc
I copied `cs2cs.exe` and `proj.dll` to a seperate folder
When i run this to convert israel tranverse mercator to decimal latlon:

```
cs2cs -f "%.10f" +init=EPSG:2039 +to +init=epsg:4326
```

It works
but when i run the opossite:

```
cs2cs -If "%.10f" +init=EPSG:2039 +to +init=epsg:4326
```

It does not work

When i run this code from latlon in degreea to israel tranverse mercator :
       `cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=EPSG:2039`

it works
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a typo with extra double quote in cs2cs" in your command or is it only in your question?

Comment: only in my question

Comment: Then I do not understand: `C:\temp\>cs2cs -f "%.10f" +init=EPSG:2039 +to +init=epsg:4326
100000 200000
33.9914757989   27.8782934566 16.3155329879`

and 

`C:\temp\>cs2cs -If "%.10f" +init=EPSG:2039 +to +init=epsg:4326
33.99 27.87
99845.5441014933        199082.2545403841 -16.3066176036`

Comment: can it be that i am missing a library or some other connection?

Comment: I don't know. I made my test with Windows binaries from gisinternals.com (GDAL-dev, v2.0), opened the command window by running "sdkshell.bat" and copied your commands. I would make three fast tests a) write the parameters separately as -I -f "%.10f" b) drop out the format parameter c) instead of -I swap the input and output epsg-codes.

Comment: Copying .exe and .dll to another place is not a good idea. To run cs2cs correctly, you have to set the environment variables using SDKshell.bat. You need more than just those two files.

Comment: for some reason when i get rid of OSgeo from my %PATH% it works, have no idea why! @Andre Joost why is it not a good idea? iwant it to work on other computers

Comment: cs2cs needs more than just the proj.dll to work.